# Storing MongoDB ID as my key on Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3

I've built functionality to simultaneously save a record in my MongoDB database and upload image(s) to Amazon S3. That's all working OK. However, in this process, I'm also wanting to save the ID of the data from my MongoDB as the key in my Amazon S3 upload.

I've tried playing around with 'req.params.id' and so on, but it's just coming back as undefined.

Is there a really obvious way of doing this? Hoping I'm missing something straightforward.

Code:

```
 const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'example',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${req.body.id}`
        // Date.now().toString()
      );
    }
  })
});

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  HouseListing.create(req.body, (error, houselisting) => {
    if (error) {
      const validationErrors = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message);
      req.flash('validationErrors', validationErrors);
      return res.redirect("/houseListing");
    }
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body.mainImages);
    console.log(req.body.id);
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```

The bottom two console logs of my Database function are returning 'undefined'. As is the upload function.

Any tips? :) Please let me know if I've missed any info out!

Comment: Is the client sending the ID in the post? I'm assuming the ID would be created by mongo, so the upload can only happen after...

Comment: Yeah apologies - I'm meaning the ID created by Mongo automatically. No input from the client.

Comment: Then it should be in houselisting._id

Comment: OK, thanks. But how do I access that in my upload call to S3 to save the key as the ID? I should probably have noted, they're in separate controllers - my S3 call is in my server.js (where my POST request is) and my database create function is in a separate file.

Comment: Well, unsepparate them I'd say... It is on the same request? Then your controller should handle it, nothing else. They are 2 different requests? Post the houselisting and then you can post the files using the ID provided... But how will you be managing the rights to upload picture for a particular listing if you do not handle it in the controller???